# Extract only the sentence portion of a section header

Tags: r

I have a small problem.

I have text that looks like:

```
B.1 My name is John
```

I want to only obtain:

```
My name is John
```

I'm having difficulty leaving out both the B and the 1, at the same time

Comment: We nee more information about what you are trying to leave out. Is it always a single letter followed by period followed by a single digit?  Might it be B.12? AA.2?  What do the labels look like?

Comment: Yes. It could be B.12, so any number of any possible length after a letter and a decimal. It does not need to detect something like AA.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `sub` and a regular expression.

```
TestStrings = c("B.1 My name is John", "A.12 This is another sentence")
sub("\\b[A-Z]\\.\\d+\\s+", "", TestStrings)
[1] "My name is John"          "This is another sentence"
```

The \\b indicates a word boundary (to eliminate multiple letters)

[A-Z] will match a single capital letter.

\\. will match a period

\\d+ will match one or more digits

\\s+ will match any training blank space.

The part that is matched will be replaced with the empty string.

Comment: I'd recommend `^` at the beginning rather than `\\b` - assuming that the section number will always start the string.

Comment: I think that is a good suggestion,  but I would then use `^\\s*` in case of spurious initial blanks spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all the strings that you need have the same (or similar) initial part you can do

```
> a<-"B.1 My name is John"
> substr(a, 5, nchar(a))
[1] "My name is John"
```